# How to add a bootstrap template to a .net 1.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-1.1

I am trying to add a bootstrap template in a .net 1.1 project along with visual studio 2003  but I am bit confused about how visual studio compiles .js and calls css

Comment: Are you really creating a new project with .NET Framework 1.1? Even .NET Framework 2.0 went out of support in July 2011. You'll be missing out on security updates, etc. by using such an old (and unsupported version).

Comment: It's a legacy code project

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use CDN instead of local files for bootstrap and after that just include the template files in project.

Check CDN Bootstrap documentation [here](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).